# Why $\mathbf{r}=l(\cos (\omega t) \mathbf{e}_x +\sin (\omega t) \mathbf{e}_y), |\mathbf{r}|=l$ solves $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-l\omega^2 \mathbf{e}_r\;?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My textbook says something equivalent to:

> $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-l\omega^2 \mathbf{e}_r=-\omega^2 \mathbf{r}, \ l=|\mathbf{r}|=\mathtt{const}$

(2d position vector $\mathbf{r}=\big(x(t), y(t)\big), | \mathbf{e} |=1$), *so* the solutions are of the type

> $\mathbf{r}=l\big(\cos(\omega t) \mathbf{e}_x +\sin (\omega t) \mathbf{e}_y\big), |\mathbf{r}|=l$.

(Then the author goes on using exactly that solution to show something else involving circular paths). I understand that a solution with free parameters can be

> $l\big(A\cos(\omega t+ \alpha)\mathbf{e}_x + B\sin(\omega t+\beta)\mathbf{e}_y\big)$

(right?). And I can deduce, since $l$ is fixed, $A=B=1, \ \alpha=\beta$ would solve the differential equation, but I cannot prove that it implies it (see the "so" in the textbook).

Does somebody know how to get the solution without the guessing, or is my guess not guessing after all and is that what the textbook meant by "so" ?

Comment: compute the derivatives involved directly. what do you get?

Comment: With the techniques that I know I get $l(A cos(\omega t+ \alpha)\mathbf{e}_x + B sin(\omega t+\beta)\mathbf{e}_y)$ like I said, not?

Comment: I guess my question is more clearly, considering a valid solution is $l(A cos(\omega t+ \alpha)\mathbf{e}_x + B sin(\omega t+\beta)\mathbf{e}_y)$ (with 4 free parameters as required), how come the textbook seem to afford the leap to setting A=B=1 and $\alpha=\beta=0$? The author seems so confident by using "so", while I don't see the implication. Maybe he got there in an entirely different way?

Comment: Notice $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-\ell\omega^2(\cos(\omega t) +\sin(\omega t))$

Comment: Thank you Oliver for your comment, but I don't get it, you are saying $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ is a scalar in your equation, typo?

Comment: I guess you are saying $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=l\omega^2\big(\cos(\omega t) \mathbf{e}_x +\sin (\omega t) \mathbf{e}_y\big)$? Ah yes, so what is meant is $\mathbf{r}=l\big(\cos(\omega t) \mathbf{e}_x +\sin (\omega t) \mathbf{e}_y\big)$, then integrating $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}$ for both $x,y$ gets you the solution with two (for the further context irrelevant) terms with constants $c_1*t+c_2$? That's brilliant, thanks! (unless I am mistaken here?)